# Is it possible to query AllegroGraph using roqet?

Tags: rdf, sparql, allegrograph

I am trying to query AllegroGraph 4.0 using roqet to extract data in CSV. Is it possible? In roqet man page it is not clear if it can query a triple store besides rdf files.

About AG HTTP protocol:
http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/http-protocol.html#header2-270

About roqet:
http://librdf.org/rasqal/roqet.html

Hello @dajobe!! Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible today, roqet cannot talk SPARQL protocol yet.  It's not a lot of work, just not implemented yet.